# Separate music instruments and estimate note density

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I have a `.wav` file of a musical performance with three instruments: a clarinet, a bass and drums. My goal is to detect the note speed played by the clarinet player (so I want the number of notes played every  five seconds: ex: between 0s and 5s = 4 notes played; between 5s and 10s = 2 notes played, etc.).

To separate I used spleeter by Deezer, and to calculate the note density, I used the librosa function `librosa.onset.onset_detect()`. However, I am note quite satisfied with the result.

Does anybody have a better idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem that can be divided into two parts :

1. Transform audio data to musical data (trying for the three instruments to be separated during this step)
2. Analyze the density of musical notes

To make the first step as consistent as possible, you should use a single library. For instance you could use an audio to midi converter (there is one python library [here](https://pypi.org/project/audio-to-midi/)) to get the musical data. Then you could do the rest of the job by yourself, counting MIDI notes and so on (which would be a lot simpler than working with audio).